# Stripe Order request with shipping price

Tags: php, callback, stripe-payments

I want to create a stripe order, but when I add the  shipping price to the array, it gives me the following error:

**Response body**

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Items of type `shipping` are not supported at order creation.",
    "param": "items[2]",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

**Request POST body**

```
{
  "items": {
    "0": {
      "type": "sku",
      "parent": "sku_11111111111",
      "quantity": "1"
    },
    "1": {
      "type": "discount",
      "amount": "0",
      "currency": "GBP",
      "description": "No discount"
    },
    "2": {
      "type": "shipping",
      "amount": "30",
      "currency": "gbp",
      "description": "Shipping"
    }
  },
  "currency": "gbp",
  "shipping": {
    "name": "name lastname",
    "address": {
      "line1": "addres",
      "city": "city",
      "state": "pr",
      "country": "AM",
      "postal_code": "123"
    }
  },
  "email": "test@test.test",
  "metadata": {
    "payment_method": "visa"
  }
}
```

Also i found [this](https://stripe.com/docs/orders/dynamic-shipping-taxes), but i don't understand **Your endpoint response** part there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's important to note first that the [Orders API](https://stripe.com/docs/orders) has been deprecated for some time and is not recommended for new integrations. Instead, I would suggest looking at [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout) for creating and fulfilling customer orders.

For Orders, the [shipping docs](https://stripe.com/docs/orders#shipping-and-taxes) explain that shipping is configured in your [dashboard settings](https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/orders). The `provider` and `callback` options require you to configure how shipping information is provided, and the "your endpoint response" section explains how a dynamic shipping callback should respond to Stripe.

If you're using the `flat-rate` configuration then the [order creation response](https://stripe.com/docs/orders#create-pay-orders) will include one or more `shipping_method` options, and you can change which is being used by sending an [update request to set the `selected_shipping_method`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/orders/update#update_order-selected_shipping_method).

Comment: I create `callback` payment method, now when trying to create order i got this error:
`Order creation failed while contacting the provider.`, How can i now what is wrong with my response?

Comment: Are you following the specification of the doc you referenced? Can you say more about why you're trying to use Orders with a new integration?

Comment: You'll need to reach out to Stripe support to have them help investigate your shipping rates callback. https://support.stripe.com/contact

Comment: What new alternative is there to Orders API ?

Comment: As noted at the top of my original answer, you should look into Checkout for a much nicer user and developer experience. It's not the same, but it plays a similar role.